# SELECTION SORT - my own version of the sort

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop, while-loop, selection

I am trying to make my own algorithm for the selectionsort. But for some reason this algorithm stops at the second last element. Could someone help me understand why my sort wont  include the last 2 elements.

```
void selection_sort(int a[],int size)
{
    int start = -1;
    int fin_index;
    int smallest;
    while(start<=size)
    {
        start++;
        fin_index = start;
        int smallest_elem = a[start];
        for(int i=start;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<smallest_elem)
            {
            smallest_elem = a[i];
            smallest = i;
            }
        }
        swap(a[fin_index],a[smallest]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your compiler give you any warnings when compiling this code?

Comment: Not really it crashes and fails to sort the last 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the "smallest" variable before entering the "for" loop.

Initialize it to `fin_index`:  `smallest = fin_index`

If the element is already at its sorted position then it will be swapped with the previous value of smallest.

Also, your while loop runs for `size+2` times. The while loop should run for only at most `size`-times, as we want the minimum only `size` times.

These two mistakes cause your implementation to fail.